# Memory leak while using MWPhotoBrowser

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, memory-management

I am using MWPhotoBrowser in my app.

Here is the delegate method which is called when I view photo in gallery:

```
-(MWPhoto*)getPhotoFromArray:(NSArray*)array atIndex:(int)index{

    ImagesDb *imageObj = [imagesArr objectAtIndex:index];

    ImagesDataDb *imageData = imageObj.data;

    MWPhoto *photo = [[MWPhoto alloc]initWithImage:imageData.orignalImage];

    return photo;

}
```

ImagesDataDb and imagesObj are CoreData Object

Everything is fine, but as I browse photos memory gets filled (as previously images were not released )
Ultimately , the app crashed due to memory problem. 
I believe that "ImagesDataDb" object(this object containd image in detail) gets alllocated in memory but It doesnt gets deallocated, even though the reference object(MWPhoto object in this case) to it gets deallocated. 
This means that object previously allocated doesnt leave memory.

Whats the solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes, I got it now.
I simple added the line
((ImagesDb*)[imagesArr objectAtIndex:index]).data = nil; to my code.
Now, what happens is that it deallocates the memory which was used by the object.

Anyways , thanks for the answers